# AG-Grid server side paging issues

Tags: ag-grid

I am looking for the below two features with AG-GRID pagination. Please let me know if it is possible with this grid.

1. I have successfully implemented service side pagination with AG-Grid. The pagination gives the options "First", "Previous", "Next" and "Last". Assume a situation that i am having 50 pages. If i want to go 40th page, i will have to press the "Next" button 40 times. This is really annoying. Is there any way that we can specify the page number using the pagination option?
2. Is there any way that i can go to a particular page during run-time or during grid on ready event?

Comment: How did u manage to do a server side paging with ag-grid?

Comment: @ssashok10 did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

gridOptions.api.paginationGoToPage(40);